# Terminal de visual studio code tiene la fuente (letra) borrosa

Tags: vscode, terminal

Reinstalé visual studio code, pero la terminal tiene la fuente (letra) borrosa, Ya intente configuraciones, temas, desinstalar y reinstalar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta añadir a settings.json la siguiente línea

`"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "canvas",`

o

`"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",`

En general desactivar la aceleración del GPU resuelve ese problema.